# Would returning a Lazy<Stream> from a method be a good idea for deferring the cost of opening a FileStream?

Tags: c#, file-io, lazy-evaluation

I have a scenario where I want to clearly convey that it's the caller's responsibility for disposing a stream while at the same time preventing the caller from discovering the underlying file's path -- the caller shouldn't know that the stream came from the file system.  Also, the caller isn't going to need the stream until later on, so I probably don't need to open it immediately.

Given that, I thought that it might be a good idea to leverage Lazy<T> for this purpose, as in:

```
public Lazy<Stream> GetContent(string key)
{
    string path = GetFilePath(key);
    return new Lazy(() => File.OpenRead(path));
}
```

Am I over-thinking this? Should I just return a Stream instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be aware that returning `Lazy<T>` in this way means that if multiple pieces of code re-use the same lazy "factory" then they will get *exactly the same stream*. For example, if one piece of code disposes the stream then the others will be attempting to use the same disposed stream etc.

If you really need to defer creation of the stream then I'd suggest returning a `Func<T>` instead. This will allow the returned delegate to be safely shared and re-used, creating a new stream instance each time it is invoked.

My own preference would probably be to just return a plain `Stream`, and *document very clearly* that it's the caller's responsibility to handle the disposal.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds right, Func<T> would be better, it's used as sort of a lightweight factory type all over the place.

Comment: I've decided to mark this one as the answer because it points out that in addition to being unnecessary, the suggested code was plain broken viz multiple callers observing the same stream.

Answer (score 3):

Lazy<> is the exact opposite, it is a creation detail, not a destruction detail.  Furthermore, the client has no decent reason to delay construction when interested in the *content*.  These are just wrong signals, return a Stream.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Based on these answers, I've decided to just return a Stream.

Answer (score 1):

> the caller shouldn't know that the stream came from the file system

Caller may cast `GetContent(key).Value` to `FileStream`. You may want to decorate it with something if the need is not to expose `FileStream`.

Anyway personally I don't see any advantages of using Lazy here.